# Warum erfordert „in den Mai tanzen“ „sein“ als Hilfsverb?

Tags: grammar, single-word-request, perfect-tense

Normalerweise hat das Verb *tanzen* als Hilfsverb *haben.* Das ändert sich wenn man in den Mai tanzt, oder? Wenn ja: wieso? Oder vielleicht geht beides?

---

Ob es um einen Regionalismus geht, weiß ich nicht. Jemand (gebürtig aus NRW) hat mir

> Ich hoffe, du bist schön in den Mai getanzt!

an irgendeinem 1.5. als Grußformel geschrieben.

Comment: Huh? Kannst du bitte ein Beispiel geben? Imho wird hier auch "haben" verwendet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hier wird das Verb »tanzen« nicht verwendet, um eine ortsfeste Betätigung auszudrücken, sondern hier hat »tanzen« die Funktion eines Verbs der Bewegung, ähnlich wie fahren, gehen oder wandern, auch wenn das Ziel (der Mai) kein realer Ort ist:

> Ich bin in das Dorf gefahren. - Ich bin in den Mai gefahren.
>   Ich bin in das Dorf gegangen. - Ich bin in den Mai gegangen.
>   Ich bin in das Dorf gewandert. - Ich bin in den Mai gewandert.
>   Ich bin in das Dorf getanzt. - **Ich bin in den Mai getanzt.**

Das Hilfsverb *haben* wird dagegen benutzt wenn man das Ausüben der Tätigkeit an sich (also ohne ein örtliches Ziel) ausdrücken möchte:

> Ich **habe** gestern mit deiner Mutter **getanzt**.

---

Belege für *bin/ist getanzt*:

- [myheimat.de](http://www.myheimat.de/burgwedel/freizeit/lions-club-isernhagenburgwedel-feiert-in-den-mai-d1736253.html)
- [brainknots.com](http://www.brainknots.com/alles-neu-macht-der-mai-und-bei-mir-ist-alles-beim-alten/)
- [weightwatchers.de](http://www.weightwatchers.de/community/mbd/post.aspx?page_size=25&rownum=5&page_noHidden=1&threadpage_no=1&sincedate=07.04.2010+00%3A00%3A00&thread_id=127271831&thread_name=Valentinas+Rubensdamen+am+Samstag+1.5.2010&forum_id=1&board_id=9&setview=TRUE&daterange=2days&viewchange=OPENDATEDESC)
- [razyboard.com](http://www.razyboard.com/system/morethread-1mai-skaten-mario_weisser-1460008-5635698-0.html)

Comment: "Ich habe in den Mai getanzt" hat mehr Google-Treffer als "Ich bin in den Mai getanzt" und für mich ist nur ersteres richtig.

Comment: @Em1: "Ich habe in den Mai getanzt" klingt für mich vollkommen falsch. Das mag daran liegen, dass, wie in dieser Antwort angedeutet, durch den Akkusativ von "in den Mai" eine Bewegung ausgedrückt wird, womit das Hilfsverb "haben" intuitiv überhaupt keinen Sinn ergibt. Auch fehlt ein Objekt, auf das der Vorgang angewendet wurde (z.B. "Ich habe *meinen Onkel* in den Urlaub gefahren."), sodass keine Antwort auf "Wer oder was wurde in den Mai getanzt?" vorliegt, was wohl auch das Hilfsverb "haben" rechtfertigen könnte. Vielleicht ist es auch hier in Südwestdeutschland anders üblich als anderswo?

Comment: Mit hingegen kommt »Ich *habe* in den Mai getanzt« falsch vor. Möglicherweise gibt es in diesem Fall regionale Unterschiede. Gölte das Google-Zähl-Argument uneingeschränkt, wäre auch der hier verwendete Konjunktiv als falsch anzusehen, weil er deutlich seltener als »würde gelten« verwendet wird. (»gölte«: 27.600 Treffer, »würde gelten«: 55.500.000)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Das Argument mit dem Objekt ist fehl am Platz. Wenn du "getanzt hast" (ohne den Mai) brauchst du doch auch kein Objekt ("Ich habe getanzt"). Wenn du nun "in den Mai tanzt", ändert sich nichts, außer dass du nicht einfach "nur getanzt" hast, sondern "in den Mai getanzt" hast.

Comment: Nach weiterer Überlegung ist für mich glaube ich BEIDES akzeptabel, wobei die Frage ist nur, wie man das ganze betrachtet. a) in den Mai *hinein* tanzen (Erklärung von Hubert) // b) schlichte Wiedergabe eines Event / einer Tätigkeit. "Haben" ist nur natürlich, weil: "Frage: Was **hast** du am Donnerstag gemacht? Antwort: Ich **habe** in den Mai getanzt" -> Die natürliche Frage ist, was man gemacht **hat**, daher wird die natürliche Antwort auch mit *haben* gebildet.

Comment: @Em1: Sehr schwaches Argument. »Was hast du am Donnerstag gemacht?« - »Ich *habe* nach München gefahren.« Ich glaube nicht, dass die Frage wirklich das Hilfsverb impliziert. Ich würde auch auf diese Frage mit »Ich *bin* nach München gefahren.« antworten. Daher ebenso: »Was hast du gestern gemacht?« - »Ich *bin* in den Mai getanzt.«

Comment: @Em1: Natürlich, wenn man nur getanzt hat (ohne, dass eine Fortbewegung impliziert ist), braucht man kein Objekt, um das Hilfsverb "haben" zu verwenden. Mir ging es darum, dass Verben, die eindeutig eine Bewegung ausdrücken und passend dazu das Hilfsverb "sein" einsetzen ("Ich *bin* in den Urlaub gefahren.") allenfalls dann ein "haben" verwenden, wenn sie mit einem Objekt zusammen stehen, auf das die Bewegung angewandt wird ("Ich *habe* meinen Onkel in den Urlaub gefahren.").

Comment: @HubertSchölnast "in den Mai tanzen" ist aber erstmal keine wirkliche Bewegung ala fahren, gehen, laufen; sondern ein "Event" ala feiern, saufen, whatever. Also: Ich habe etwas gemacht und zwar habe ich in den Mai getanzt. Ich empfinde hier die Verwendung und Begrüdung von "sein" übrigens super unlogisch, immerhin bewegt sich kein Schwein "in" den Mai. Und doch ist es nachvollziehbar (bei Sprache ist oft so einiges nicht logisch), weswegen ich es als Erklärung akzeptiere. Ich werde aber am Freitag dann trotzdem das Hilfsverb "haben" benutzen. :)

Comment: Ich könnte mir vorstellen, dass wir es hier wieder mal mit einem Nord/Süd-Unterschied zu tun habe - immerhin werden im Süden auch alle Verben die Zustände beschreiben (zB sitzen, stehen) "sein" gebildet. Wobei ich jetzt trotz allem tanzen eigentlich mit "haben" bilden würde.

Comment: @Em1: Dann denke deine ganze Argumentation mal nicht mit »in den Mai« sondern »in das Dorf hinein« durch. Das wirst du ja hoffentlich als tatsächliches örtliches Ziel anerkennen. Dann hast du: »Ich *bin* in das Dorf hinein getanzt.« Würdest du auch hier *bin* durch *habe* ersetzen?. Achja: Ich habe etwas gemacht. Ich *habe* nach München gefahren. = Schwaches Argument (hatten wir schon)

Comment: @Gerhard: Das dachte ich anfangs auch, aber alle Beispiele mit »bin/ist getanzt« habe ich auf Seiten in Deutschland gefunden, nicht in Österreich. Auch der Schluss von den Zustandsverben auf das Verb *tanzen* ist nicht so recht überzeugend.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Wenn ich in das Dorf tanze, dann bewege ich mich tanzend in das Dorf hinein. In den Mai kann man aber sich nie und nimmer hineinbewegen. Impossible.

Comment: @em1: ich finde schon, dass man sich im übertragenen Sinne (zeitlich) in den Mai hinein bewegen kann.

Comment: @Em1... wie sieht's mit "zur Bar rüber tanzen" aus? Für mich geht da NUR "sein" und analog bei "in den Mai" auch, denn Ort und Zeit sind im Prinzip dasselbe. Die Bewegtheit ist ja hier auch klar über den Fall sichtbar. Und wo wir dabei sind... was ist mit "ins neue Jahr rutschen"? Ich kann mir schwer vorstellen, dass du da "hast du gut reingerutscht" sagst. Müsstest du nach deiner Logik aber.

Comment: @Emanuel Tatsächlich verwende ich beim neuen Jahr "sein". Gutes Beispiel. Beim Maitanz ist aber de facto "habe" durchaus gängig(er), zumindest in meiner Gegend.